# C# use SymmetricAlgorithm wihtout CryptoStream

Tags: c#, encryption

I want to encrypt my variable-length commands with a `SymmetricAlgorithm` like `Aes` (`AesCryptoServiceProvider`). My usage is not compatible with streams.

I like to implement Encrypt and Decrypt methods that get and return byte array. However, .NET has a bit awkward and weird implementation for doing so. AFAIK I must deal with `ICryptoTransform`, which have poor documented and only have to methods.

The problem is:

1. when I use `TransformFinalBlock` like this:
   `return Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length)`
    it works but it doesn't change `IV` so it always returns the same output for the same input;
2. when I use `TransformBlock` it updates `IV` but it doesn't accept my variable length commands, and apparently I must pad it to block size myself.

Does anyone have a better idea to simply encrypt variable length commands with a symmetric algorithm  in C#?

For instance, with a prototype like this:
`byte[] Encrypt(byte[] arbitraryLengthData)`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to simply create a separate `ICryptoTransform` for each encryption procedure. That should solve the IV problem. Then the only thing that needs to be kept is the symmetric key. Ciphers are lightweight constructions, they don't take much time to instantiate or initiate.

Otherwise, you could set a random IV explicitly, but I'd prefer the previous method.

---

I don't know *why* the streaming operation is not compatible with your use case. Using streaming is just a convenience layer on top of the library that uses `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock`. It is perfectly possible to use a stream to **implement** your `Encrypt` method. I don't see any reason why it would be "not compatible with streams", even if there is just a single update.

The streaming API is at least more logical than using a single `TransformFinalBlock` to encrypt / decrypt multiple blocks, if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks! creating a new IV for every operation is not possible because parties must exchange IVs! in short, every operation must 1-do padding data 2-udpate IV, and each of ICryptoTransform methods does one of this ops and discard other. so probably i must do the other Op myself! but is there a separate method for apply padding or update IV? or i must write them from scratch?

Comment: If you just stick to the `Aes` class then the IV is a property. And I already indicated that you could just recreate the object / cipher / transform, right?

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what exactly you say! can you provide a little code? do you say that i can XOR result with my IV for example to update it manually?